# Renomear coluna com o entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Gostaria de saber como posso resolver o seguinte problema.
Tenho a classe abaixo:

```
namespace CustomizandoCodeFirstMigrations.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class AlteraTelefoneFixoRenomeiaCelular : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            RenameColumn("dbo.Pessoas", "Celular", "TelefoneCelular");
            AlterColumn("dbo.Pessoas", "TelefoneFixo", c => c.String(nullable: false, unicode: false));
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            RenameColumn("dbo.Pessoas", "TelefoneCelular", "Celular");
            AlterColumn("dbo.Pessoas", "TelefoneFixo", c => c.String());
        }
    }
}
```

E quando digito no package manager console o comando update-database recebo como resposta:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: Preciso de mais duas informações antes de responder: o retorno de `select * from Pessoas` e `select * from __MigrationHistory`.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez O retorno de `select * from pessoas` é: `1, João Batista, joaobatista@email.com, (12)1234-5678, (12)99778-0000` e o retorno de `select * from __MigrationHistory` é `201512231623056_InitialCreate, CustomizandoCodeFirstMigrations.K19Context, blob, 6.1.3-40302`

Comment: Caso considerem importante, ao executar o comando update-database -force -verbose, recebo como parte da resposta: `set @columnType := (select case lower(IS_NULLABLE) when 'no' then CONCAT(column_type, ' not null ')  when 'yes' then column_type end from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Pessoas' and column_name = 'Celular');
set @sqlstmt := (select concat('alter table `Pessoas` change `Celular` `TelefoneCelular` ' , @columnType));
prepare stmt from @sqlstmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;`

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Agradeço a ajuda. Um colega de um grupo do facebook explicou-me que poderia ser o fato de existir outra tabela com o mesmo nome em outro schema. Deletei o schema anterior e executei o comando update-database e tudo funcionou.

Comment: Vou apenas sintetizar uma resposta, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu comando `verbose`, temos:

```
set @columnType := (select 
                     case lower(IS_NULLABLE) 
                         when 'no' then         
                             CONCAT(column_type, ' not null ') 
                         when 'yes' then 
                             column_type 
                         end 
                     from information_schema.columns 
                     where table_name = 'Pessoas' 
                     and column_name = 'Celular'); 
 set @sqlstmt := (select concat('alter table Pessoas 
                                 change Celular TelefoneCelular ', @columnType)); 
 prepare stmt from @sqlstmt; 
 execute stmt; 
 deallocate prepare stmt;`
```

O comando `@columnType` recebia duas ocorrências de `Pessoa`, por isso seu erro.

Apagar o *schema* é um caminho, mas sou a favor de uma solução mais branda, que seria apagar apenas a tabela `Pessoa` deste outro *schema*.